# I get Bsod with either Memory Management or Faulty Hardware Corrupted Page error and changes on files are deleted on reboot

Tags: windows-10, memory-management, black-screen-of-death

I get Blue Screen of Death on Windows 10, most of the times Memory Management related, but also Faulty Hardware Corrupted Page. I also noticed that when I write/delete a file and then restart the computer, changes are not being made. I've tried to run /scannow but I get Bsod before it is completed. Now I am getting a notification that sais "scan hard drive for errors" and when I click that nothing happens. What is more, Mozilla (the browser) thinks that it is the first run of the program and it keeps showing a First Run (wellcoming) page each time I open the computer. The worst thing is that Windows Update service cannot start and it is somehow stopped. What do you think is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: As a quick test, in an admin prompt, what does:
`wmic diskdrive get model, status`
return?
Is it a SSD?

Comment: @HelpingHand Yes it is a SSD. What I get is Model: SATAFIRM S11 and Status: OK

Comment: What about running: `chkdsk /f C:`?

Comment: @HelpingHand chkdsk /f C: sais Cannot run.. chkdsk alone works up to certain moment then BSOD shows up.

Comment: Do you have a minidump of the bugcheck?  It should be under: C:\windows\minidump\.  Maybe you can upload it to: http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=Analyze and provide the output here or provide a link to the minidump itself.  If you perform the same steps twice the cause the issue, is the dump the same or different?